# Preserving gwei after math

Tags: solidity, local-variables

Is it possible to preserve a currency designation after performing calculations? For example, using Remix, in variable declaration I have something like this:

```
uint256 myConstant = 100 gwei;
uint256 newNum;
```

Once the constructor executes, a calculation is performed, e.g.:

```
newNum = myConstant + 10;
```

In a subsequent function, the user is required to submit the correct amount in the Remix Value field; the code includes a conditional `msg.value != newNum`, then throw an error. Thus, in this case, when I specify 110 gwei in the Value field, the error is thrown. My guess is that once I perform some math on the original `myConstant` variable in gwei, that those units are lost? I've tried adding the keyword **gwei** to the variable declaration for `newNum` and the formula line; neither option is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gwei, ether, days, hours etc. All these keywords make the code more readable and easy to understand. In your case myConstant still holds the value `100000000000` so when you add 10 it becomes `100000000010` but not `110000000000`(110 Gwei)

Comment: Yep, that was it. I had to use the _wei_ conversion instead. Thanks.